# Increment row position every time a script runs

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am currently storing a value each day using the function below:

```
function addTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateCell").timeBased().atHour(13).everyDays(1).create();
}

function updateCell() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12yxNcp0n5_-------------d6B81m6QcjrKXTQDvyx0/edit#gid=377838361";
  var cellOut = "L23";
  var cellIn = "B19";
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getRange(cellIn).getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getRange(cellOut).setValue(value);
}
```

I would like to be able to increment the row value each time that the script is run. Since the variable call is done at each run of the script I would assume that there is no global variables to use. So how could one have a variable that increment with each run of the script.

I have read about using PropertiesService to make a sort of global variable, however there must be some more standardized way to increment a value for each time a script is run in google sheets scripts.

I am fully aware that I need to set my Range using Col and Row arguments so I do not need assistance on that, but on how to increment the value that I can put in as the Row.

Truly thankful for your help

Comment: If you describe what is the goal that you wan to achieve with your script maybe I could give you a more specific answer than the one that I already posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general sense, in Google Apps Script, the most "standardized way" to have a variable that increments on each execution (a persistent variable) that we could use is the [Google Apps Script Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)

Another common way is to save the row number is to save it in a spreadsheet cell.

Comment: thank you, saving the row number in a cell will solve the issue I have. I guess I have overlooked that possibility all this time. Again huge thanks